# Combining lists by category and creating new column with description for each list

Tags: python, list, perl, scripting, command

I have 15 .txt lists which I would like to combine by category and keep each list's description separate in a new column. Unfortunately, not all categories are present in each list, and the descriptions will need to correspond with the correct category.

For example, if two of my lists look something like:

```
List 1:
1   a
4   b
5   c
2   d



List 2:
3   a
6   c
7   f
2   g
```

I am looking for an output such as (but for the eventual 15 files to be combined):

```
category List1 List2    
a   1   3
b   4   
c   5   6 
d   2   
f       7
g       2
```

Does anyone have scripting suggestions to help make this happen?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PYTHON solution:

I imagine that your files contain data in this way:

```
1   a
4   b
5   c
2   d
```

Here is my example code and I will explain what's  going on.

```
files = ['test1.txt', 'test2.txt']
category_dict = dict()
for _file in files:
    with open(_file, 'r') as fhl:
        for line in fhl:
            key, val = line.split()
            if key in category_dict:
                category_dict[key].append(val)
            else:
                category_dict[key] = [val]
print(category_dict)
```

Result of the print:

```
{'1': ['a'], '4': ['b'], '5': ['c'], '2': ['d', 'g'], '3': ['a'], '6': ['c'], '7': ['f']}
```

First I create a simple list of all the files I want to read. Note that you can os.walk ( check it online) to grab all files you want from a directory, or you can simply add fails in this list (full pat).

```
files = ['test1.txt', 'test2.txt']
```

Then we create a dictionary object to store our data in the way you wanted:

```
category_dict = dict()
```

Then we loop through the file list and we open each file and we read it line by line:

```
for _file in files:
    with open(_file, 'r') as fhl:
        for line in fhl:
```

Here is the interesting part. If the file is not exactly in the format you showed above, you might get and error or read the data not in the way you want. Check your files and adjust the 'split()' part if needed.

Furthermore, we split (check it online), basically split a string into list of words.

```
key, val = line.split()
```

Note that if they are not separated by space you might need to adjust the line above.

After that we check if the 'key' is presented in the 'category_dict', if not, we create it and then make it equal to a list of the value we got from the file. If the key is already there, that means that we already assigned a list of a value/values to that 'key'. Then we just append the new value.

This way you will have a 'category' and keep each 'key' values separately.

EDIT:
If you want to record the result in a file (txt extension), each value in the dict to be written on a new line, here is example:

```
with open('results.txt', 'w+') as fhl:
    for key in category_dict:
        fhl.write('{} {}'.format(key, ' '.join(category_dict[key])))
        fhl.write('\n')
```

Result:

```
1 a
4 b
5 c
2 d g
3 a
6 c
7 f
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! This appears to read my files fine. The only thing being that I would like to print the output to a new txt file which keeps each list's results in a new column.
category List 1 List 2
a   1   3
b   4   
c   5   6 
d   2   
f       7
g       2
(oops, I'm not sure how to format the output here, so edited the original post to show the type of output format I am hoping to be able to get in the final document.) Thanks!

Comment: I edited my original post to include writing to file in the format you want.

Comment: This is getting so close! The only thing is that I need to ensure each file remains in its own column. For example, if file 1 and 2 both have information for 'a' than the first line will be "a 1 3". But if only file two has information for 'g' for example, then the line in the document will be "g  2" with an extra space between the g and the 2, signifying that it belongs to the second file. Sorry, this is a bit confusing. I have tried showing this in the example output above, with tabs separating the columns. Alternatively, these could be printed as a csv if that would be easier?

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
files = glob.glob('*.txt')
#eg: files = ['1.txt','2.txt']
result = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file,delimiter='  ')
    current_col = df.columns[0]
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.set_index(current_col,inplace=True)
    df.index.name = 'index'
    df.rename(columns={'index':current_col}, inplace=True)
    result = pd.concat([result,df],axis=1)

>>> result
    List 1:  List 2:
 a      1.0      3.0
 b      4.0      NaN
 c      5.0      6.0
 d      2.0      NaN
 f      NaN      7.0
 g      NaN      2.0

>>> result.fillna(0)
    List 1:  List 2:
 a      1.0      3.0
 b      4.0      0.0
 c      5.0      6.0
 d      2.0      0.0
 f      0.0      7.0
 g      0.0      2.0
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks like it will work well. However, I am getting an error: File "count.py", line 3, in <module> result=pd.DataFrame() NameError: name 'pd' is not defined". I thought this might be an error in my python version, but I have tried running both v3 and v2 with no luck.

Comment: my bad, pls import pandas as pd

Comment: Ah! Yes, I appreciate the help! But now the error is: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  df = pd.read_csv(file,delimiter='  ')
create_count_file4.py:14: FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version of pandas will change to not sort by default.
To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'...

Comment: ... ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators 

I am sorry I am not more familiar with Python.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay. And thank you again for the help! I was able to remedy my error by reinstalling python, but I wonder if you might be able to help me print the results to a new txt file? Thank you!